# Accessing Vuex store in Nuxt project from JS file

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt project I have a file named "apiAccess.js" in the root folder.  This file simply exports a bunch of functions that make Ajax calls to the server API.  This file is imported in any page that needs access to the server API.  I need to send a JWT token with each of these api requests, and I have stored that token in the Vuex store.

I need to access the JWT token from the Vuex store within this "apiAccess.js" file.  Unfortuntaely, this.$store is not recognized within this file.  How do I access the Vuex store from within this file?  Or should I have done something differently?

Here's a snippet from the apiAccessjs file where I try to access the store:

```
import axios from 'axios'
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
  json: true,
  headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer' + this.$store.state.auth.token }
})
```

Comment: `nuxt` have a axios module to be used as a plugin where you can config the axios instance and there you can access to the context app includes vuex store.

Comment: Okay.  I'm looking into that now.  Thanks!

Comment: I resolved this by placing all my api Access functions in my Vuex store as actions.  That gave me access to the context and $axios.

Comment: also you can use `inject` feature to handle your api endpoints from anywhere side of your app

Answer (score 0):

After i readed this [post](https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxt-api-call-organization-and-decoupling/) i used this generic structure:

```
// generic actions file
import {
  SET_DATA_CONTEXT,
  SET_ITEM_CONTEXT
} from '@/types/mutations'

// PAGEACTIONS
export const getDataContext = api => async function ({ commit }) {
  const data = await this[api].get()
  commit(SET_DATA_CONTEXT, data)
}

export const getItemContext = api => async function ({ commit }, id) {
  const data = await this[api].getById(id)
  commit(SET_ITEM_CONTEXT, data)
}

export const createItemContext = api => async function ({}, form) {
  await this[api].create(form)
}

export const updateItemContext = api => async function ({}, form) {
  await this[api].update(form)
}

export const deleteItemContext = api => async function ({}, id) {
  await this[api].delete(id)
}
```

and for any store i used actions from my generic file:

```
// any store file
import {
  getDataContext,
  getItemContext,
  createItemContext,
  updateItemContext,
  deleteItemContext,
  setDynamicModal
} from '@/use/store.actions'


const API = '$rasterLayerAPI'

export const state = () => ({
  dataContext: [],
  itemContext: {},
})

export const actions = {
  createItemContext: createItemContext(API),

  getDataContext: getDataContext(API),

  getItemContext: getItemContext(API),

  updateItemContext: updateItemContext(API),

  deleteItemContext: deleteItemContext(API),
}
```

because I had many stores with similar features.
and the same for `mutations` i used generic mutations functions.